# Is it possible to boot a "shut down" system over a network through an application(code) on the network?

Tags: network-programming

I was just wondering if by any means an application can boot up a system that has been previously shutdown within the same network.

This taught came to my mind after a friend just told me how his system always powers on by itself after he shuts it down. The boot does not happen immediately though.

Is it possible and what are the options? I would really doubt it is possible, but i would love to clear these doubts, please.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need hardware-support for [Wake on LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)

Comment: One more question. To use WOL is the system on standy or has been shut down?

Comment: You also need to configure your router to forward port 9 to 255.255.255.255 (IP Broadcast-To-All address) if you want to wake the machine up from outside your network.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/WOL.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/wolclass.aspx